# Superconductivity and LR Time Constant

Tags: current, resistance, inductance, time

It takes a certain time for current to reach it's maximum value(i.e steady state at 99% or 100%), and that times is(to my knowledge) determined by the value of inductance(L) and resistance(R) of a conductor. If a superconductor is used instead of a normal conductor(like copper), how would things change? If we assume R=0. And since some superconductors have quite low inductance due to their small diameters,[example](http://www.supercon-wire.com/content/nb3sn-superconducting-wires).

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have ideal voltage or current sources to go with the superconductor

Comment: Then how can some of these products labeled as superconductors function? I'm assuming the actual resistance is not zero but significantly at low resistance & inductance?

Comment: A superconductor is simply a material of no resistance (at a given temperature, magnetic flux density etc.) The circuit still has to be fed from some sort of voltage or current source, none of which are  **ideal.** Simply substituting a superconductive material in the circuit does not get away from some finite resistance **in other circuit elements.** We simply can't get infinite current or infinite voltage or infinite magnetic flux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V = L di/dt.

Apply a fixed pure voltage source across a pure inductor and the current rises and continues to rise until the superconductor cannot sustain its superconductivity any more.